# Anyway to Extend Storyboard.Children?

Tags: silverlight, animation, extension-methods, storyboard

Is there a way to extend `Storyboard.Children` to have an `.AddRange` instead of just an `.Add`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [C# extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) is a convenient way to provide an AddRange method. Be aware it won't be any faster than calling Add multiple times.

Here's one example (you might want to add error checking for nulls and such).

To use, you can either:

`sb.Children.AddRange(timelineInst1, timelineInst2);`

or pass a list.

`sb.Children.AddRange(timelineInsts);`

where `timelineInst` is a list that implements `IEnuermable<Timeline>`.

```
public static class StoryboardExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange(this TimelineCollection timeline, IEnumerable<Timeline> timelines)
    {
        foreach (Timeline t in timelines)
        {
            timeline.Add(t);
        }
    }

    public static void AddRange(this TimelineCollection timeline, params Timeline[] timelines)
    {
        if (timeline == null || timelines.Length == 0) { return; }
        foreach (Timeline t in timelines)
        {
            timeline.Add(t);
        }

    }
}
```